# If the derivative of $x^2$ is a straight line, then what is the derivative of a general exponential function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I may sound a little silly, but I've been breaking my brain over derivatives lately, so I really need an intuitive explanation for this. I know that $x^2$ has a derivative of $2x$, which can be noted graphically if one where to analyze it. But what about, say, $2^x$? My teacher told me that the derivative would be a curve of similar fashion, but I don't understand why. Why is this one's derivative a curve and not the quadratic's? I can sort of see why it wouldn't be a straight line (it would be a straight line approaching 0 from the right, as per my thinking, which doesn't make much sense), but I still don't understand how to obtain the derivative of an exponential completely. Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: This requires knowing the definition of the derivative. Do you know the definition (via limits)?

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I do! I believe it's lim (h->0) (f(x+h)-f(x))/h, correct?

Comment: Basically, if $f(x)=2^x,$ then $f(x+1)=2f(x),$ so $f' (x+1)=2f'(x).$ Therefore $f'(x)$ cannot be a line, because it grows exponentially.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews a couple things I need clarification on: 1. why did you replace h with 1? What does it mean if h is approaching 1 instead of 0? 2. why is f(x) suddenly 2f(x)? It looks like you're using the definition of the derivative to prove this, unless I'm mistaken. Regardless, I do somewhat understand, but am a little confused haha

Comment: $f(x)$ doesn't "become" $2f(x).$ What did I actually write?

Comment: Saying the same things others have said, the Taylor series expansion of $2^x$ includes powers of $x$ higher than $2$ and hence when you differentiate you are still left with non-linear powers of $x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh wait I think I see it now, but I'm still confused. how is 2^(x+1) equivalent to 2(2^x)? How did you come to that?

Comment: @sku hm, never heard of that! I'll probably do a little research on that later. But the idea does make more sense to me. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

As Sean Roberson says, this requires the definition of a limit.

For $x^n$, we can evaluate this limit as

$$\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{(x+h)^n - x^n}{h}} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{nhx^{n-1}+{n \choose 2}h^2x^{n-2} + \dots}{h}}=nx^{n-1}$$

And so, for a quadratic $f(x) =ax^2 + bx + c$, we have the straight-line derivative $f'(x) = 2ax + b$.

For $a^x$, on the other hand, our limit is

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a^x= \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{a^{x+h} - a^x}{h}} &= \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(a)}(x+h)} - \mathrm{e}^{\ln{(a)}x}}{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(h)}}}}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(a)}x}\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(a)}h} - \mathrm{e}^{\ln{(a)}x}}{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(h)}}}}\\
&= \mathrm{e}^{\ln{(a)}x}\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(a)}h}}{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(h)}}} - \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{(h)}}}}\\
&= a^x \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{a^h - a^0}{h}} = a^x \frac{\mathrm{d}a^x}{\mathrm{d}x}(0)\end{aligned}$$

So there is some number $A = \frac{\mathrm{d}a^x}{\mathrm{d}x}(0)$ such that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}a^x = Aa^x$. Thus the derivative of $a^x$ is a scaled copy of $a^x$. (As it turns out, $A = \ln{(a)}$.)